# Calendar App is blocked when users try to sync their calendar

Tags: console, passwords, google-oauth, product, migrate

Thank you in advance for your help!

We have a CRM system that allows users to sync their Calendars using the Calendar API.  The application ID of the Calendar project is not associated with our GSuite organization and we have not been able to troubleshoot the account.  The calendar application was created using a non-company email address through GSuite and we no longer have access to the application.  Our company is approved by Google for the Restricted Scope after an audit by Leviathan.

We are trying to receive help from Google Support and submitted a ticket through https://support.google.com/googleone/contact/googleone_chat but are not getting anywhere and were told to come to Stackoverflow.

This is an access issue with the project being assigned to a non-organization user and we need to have the Calendar project moved to our existing GSuite organization with the help of the proper department.

There's a 2-step solution that we need assistance with. The first step is to ask for Google's help to identify which email the Calendar API project is part of.  The second step is for Google to move the project to our GSuite Organization.

[Our users are seeing this message when syncing their CRM Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoeYP.png)

Our users are currently unable to sync their calendars.  This is very important that our clients are able to sync their calendar without seeing an error.

Thank you,

Dimitri

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Its not programming related OP should contact Google.

Comment: Either get access to the project and transfer the owner ship to that of one on your domain.  or move on and create a new project on Google developer console using your domain email as owner.   I doubt greatly you will get any help from google on this.